# Handling SSE requests using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to handle a SSE request which gives response in the form of event stream, but Jmeter is giving error

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
```

Is there any element to handle such request?

Answer (score 0):

As of latest JMeter version ([JMeter 5.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-released-td5728235.html)) there is no [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) support, you should probably consider switching to [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) tool which has [SSE support](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/sse/).

If you would like to stay with JMeter you can still test SSE, however you will have to use [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and handle the SSEs using [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) scripting. Check out [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-sse-services-with-jmeter) article for more details if interested.

Comment: i tried the links which u mentioned, now response code is 200 but still i am not getting  any response data

Comment: @Dimitri could u please help with a plugin?